# How to delegate exception to global exception in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is typical code in controller Laravel:

```
public function create(CreateInvoiceRequest $request)
    {

        try {

            $invoice = Invoice::create(['']);

            return response()->json($model);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return \Response::json(["errors" => $e->getMessage()], 400);
        }
    }
```

In exception case I catch it and show message, how to delagate (move) this in global exception Laravel? Need I do something like this?

```
try { } } catch (\Exception $e) { throw new Exception($e); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a nice solution for this. In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors) we are told to do this kind of exception handeling in `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

A very simple example could be the following:

```
// Your controller.

try {

    $invoice = Invoice::create(['']);

    return response()->json($model);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new CustomException('Invoice creation failed.');
}

// app\Exceptions\Handler.php

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I tried to find out if `create` would throw a specific exception. Unfortunately I could not find it out so quickly. If this was the case, you could remove the `try catch` and just listen to this specific exception in the `render` method.

**Update**

(not tested)

In addition, you can also overwrite the `save` method to prevent from having to wrap (all) database writing method calls with a `try` and `catch`.

We will need a `BaseModel` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Exceptions\ModelSaveException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;

class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    /**
     * Save the model to the database.
     *
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     * @throws \App\Exceptions\ModelSaveException
     */
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        try {
            return parent::save($options);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            throw new ModelSaveException($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Your controller will look cleaner without `try catch`:

```
$invoice = Invoice::create(['']);

return response()->json($model);
```

As an extra we can check if our model was being created of updated by making is of the `exists` property.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class ModelSaveException extends \Exception
{
    /**
     * ModelSaveException constructor.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
     public function __construct($model)
     {
        if ($model->exists) {
            parent::__construct('Failed updating model.');
        } else {
            parent::__construct('Failed creating model.');
        }
     }
}
```

Ofcourse don't forget to extend from you newly created model:

```
use App\Models\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom renderable exception.

```
try {
    // Your code...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \App\Exceptions\CustomException('Your message');
}
```

> Instead of type-checking exceptions in the exception handler's report and render methods, you may define report and render methods directly on your custom exception. When these methods exist, they will be called automatically by the framework:

```
/**
 * Report the exception.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function report()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request)
{
    return response(...);
}
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#renderable-exceptions